# Not Feeling Right about Data Access Design using Many Methods

Tags: oop, design-patterns

When I started I had an interface:

```
public interface IBlogReader
{
    BlogPost GetLatest();
    IEnumerable<BlogPost> FindByDate(DateTime from, int limit);
    IEnumerable<BlogPost> FindByCategory(string category, int limit);
    IEnumerable<BlogPost> FindByAuthor(string author, int limit);
}
```

Then I needed different permutations of the queries (FindByAuthorWithCategory, FindByDateWithAuthor, etc.) I figured I needed to change the approach as this would keep growing. I need more and different queries. Next I had an interface such as:

```
public struct FindCriteria
{
    DateTime? from;
    string category;
    string author;
}

public interface IBlogReader
{
    BlogPost GetLatest();
    IEnumerable<BlogPost> Find(FindCriteria criteria);
}
```

The interface was smaller and I could refrain from making many methods. However,  I basically moved the many method implementation into a big-honking single method implementation. It made me feel better for a while. I was thinking of moving to an approach that wrapped the big-honking query method into a series of individual objects where each object handled the specifics and I call for the results:

```
public abstract class QueryCommand
{
    protected IBlogReader reader = null;
    public QueryCommand(IBlogReader reader)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public abstract void Execute();
}

public class GetLatest : QueryCommand
{
    public BlogPost GetResults();
    public void Execute();
}

public class FindByDate : QueryCommand
{
    public IEnumerable<BlogPost> GetResults();
    public void Execute();
}
```

It still doesn't feel right. I read about the Repository pattern and I don't see how it applies. It seemed to me that I would still end up with the many methods in the end. The data is being stored in the cloud. Using the Specification pattern would be too heavy weight as my reading of it would bring all of the records local to qualification. In another attempt I created individual DAO objects and wrapped them inside of a repository-like facade object. The end result was the same as I began with...many methods...but the repository didn't do all of the work.

Should I just resolve myself to having either many methods or many objects and get over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Query Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html).
Sometimes we also use variation of it:

```
public class Filter
{
    public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastComment { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

And then resolving non-null criteria to filter expression.

Comment: Yes but it seems to me like jamming all of the methods into a single method. Sure the filter contains all of the parameters but the logic is still going to be somewhere. It seems to me that there is no real difference other than location of the code.

Comment: Yep, the only way to get rid of this code is to use some library that contains it. Let's imagine library that builds it based on attributes, for example. I'm afraid there is no way to do this without code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just expose an `IQueryable<BlogPost>`? The problem you describe is exactly why this approach makes sense.

Here is your interface, modified:

```
public interface IBlogReader
{
    IQueryable<BlogPost> Posts { get; }
}
```

Then you could just perform queries:

```
IBlogReader myReader = new MyReader();
var latest = myReader.Posts.Last();
var posts = myReader.Posts.Where(x => x.Author == "John Smith");
```

And so on.

Note that there are already a bunch of data access solutions that support this apporach, such as LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, or NHibernate.